# Change image inside of a single UITableViewCell when button tapped in DetailViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my detail view controller (DetailViewController.m), a notification to change an image in a UITableViewCell type is fired. I have two types of UITableViewCells. That said, when acceptButton or declineButton is tapped, I ONLY want the image to change in 1 specific cell (specifically, an image in the tapped cell that opens the detail view - not in all cells of that type). How might I go about doing this? Here's my code so far:

**DetailViewController.m**

```
  - (IBAction)acceptButton:(id)sender {

        if (!checked1) {

            [self.acceptCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedgreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            checked1 = YES;

             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ImageChangeNotification" object:nil];

            AcceptedViewController *detailViewController = [[AcceptedViewController alloc]
                                                               initWithNibName:@"AcceptedViewController" bundle:nil];


            [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

        }

        else if (checked1) {

            [self.acceptCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedgray.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            checked1 = NO;

        }

    }

- (IBAction)declineButton:(id)sender {

    if (!checked2) {

        [self.declineCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"declinered.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked2 = YES;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Declined" object:nil];

        DeniedViewController *detailViewController = [[DeniedViewController alloc]
                                                            initWithNibName:@"DeniedViewController" bundle:nil];


        [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

    else if (checked2) {

        [self.declineCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"declinegray.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked2 = NO;

    }
}
```

**TableViewCellB.m**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(changeImage)
                                                 name:@"ImageChangeNotification"
                                               object:nil];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(declineImage)
                                                 name:@"Declined"
                                               object:nil];   
}

-(void)changeImage
{
    [self.displayedBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greenbar.png"]];
    self.Title.text = @"Accepted!";

}


-(void)declineImage
{
    [self.displayedBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redbar.png"]];
    self.Title.text = @"Declined!";

}
```

**TableViewController.m** (incase it's needed)

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


        NSDictionary *data = self.messages[indexPath.row];

        id swaptime = data[@"swaptime"];
        if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

            static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier2 = @"SwapDetailTableViewCell";

            SwapDetailTableViewCell *cell = (SwapDetailTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];

            NSString *time = data[@"swaptime"];
            cell.startTime.text = time;

            NSString *timeEnd = data[@"endswaptime"];
            cell.endTime.text = timeEnd;

            NSString *costofSwap = data[@"swapvalue"];
            cell.swapValue.text = costofSwap;
      return cell;

        } else {
            static NSString *ChatTableIdentifier = @"ChatTableViewCell";

            ChatTableViewCell *cell = (ChatTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:ChatTableIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

            NSString *userName = data[@"name"];
            cell.sendingUser.text = userName;

            NSString *messageBody = data[@"body"];
            cell.messageDisplayed.text = messageBody;

            NSString *timeReceived = data[@"published at"];
            cell.timeStamp.text = timeReceived;


            NSString *userInfo = [self.userid objectForKey:@"name"];


            if ([cell.sendingUser.text isEqual: userInfo]) {

                cell.messageDisplayed.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
                cell.sendingUser.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;


                [cell.chatBubble setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubblegrey2.png"]];


            } else {

             cell.messageDisplayed.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
             cell.sendingUser.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;


                [cell.chatBubble setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bubbleorange2.png"]];

            }


            return cell;
        }
    }

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSDictionary *data = self.messages[indexPath.row];

    id swaptime = data[@"swaptime"];

    if ([swaptime isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {

    SwapDetailsViewController *detailViewController = [[SwapDetailsViewController alloc]
                                                        initWithNibName:@"SwapDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

        detailViewController.indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        detailViewController.delegate = self;


    detailViewController.swapDetails = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else {


    }

}
```

Comment: Delegate would be the better solution.
Pass the indexPath to detail controller and On button click using delegate to call the method in masterViewController and get the cell based on selected index path and change the image.

Comment: @SandeepKumar Can you post this in an answer w/ code? Not sure how I would go about implementing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface DetailViewController ()
{
    UIImage *_yourImage;
}
```

Then change it how u need it in `declineButton` or `acceptButton` and do `[tableView reloadData]`.

Comment: Doesn't this still change the image in all cells of one type though? Vs. a single specified cell?

Comment: @Brittany use image only for configuration specified cell

Answer (score 0):

In DetailViewController.h create protocol and create a property of it as below.

```
@protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)acceptButton:(BOOL)accepted withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath;

@end

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<DetailViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
// other properites and methods ....

@end
```

IN MasterViewController

While pushing detailViewController pass the indexpath and set the delegete to self and confirm, implement delegate method, as below

```
@interface MasterViewController () <DetailViewControllerDelegate>
// other properties....
@end

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {

        DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
        controller.indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        controller.delegate = self;
        // Other code...
    }
}

- (void)acceptButton:(BOOL)accepted withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (accepted) {
        // do accepted stuff
    } else {
        // do decline stuff
    }
}
```

IN DetailViewController.m

Implement the accept and decline button action

```
 - (IBAction)acceptButton:(id)sender {

    if (!checked1) {
        [self.acceptCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedgreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked1 = YES;
        /// calling delegate method
        [self.delegate acceptButton:YES withIndexPath:self.indexPath];
        AcceptedViewController *detailViewController = [[AcceptedViewController alloc]
                                                        initWithNibName:@"AcceptedViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

    } else if (checked1) {
        [self.acceptCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedgray.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked1 = NO;
    }
}

- (IBAction)declineButton:(id)sender {

    if (!checked2) {
        [self.declineCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"declinered.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked2 = YES;
        /// calling delegate method
        [self.delegate acceptButton:NO withIndexPath:self.indexPath];
        DeniedViewController *detailViewController = [[DeniedViewController alloc]
                                                      initWithNibName:@"DeniedViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if (checked2) {
        [self.declineCheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"declinegray.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        checked2 = NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, when I add <DetailViewControllerDelegate> to my interface line in DetailViewController.h, it throws me the warning: "acceptSwap:withIndexPath:' in protocol 'DetailViewControllerDelegate' not implemented?

Comment: You have to confirm the protocol  (add  <DetailViewControllerDelegate>) in MasterViewController not in DetailViewController